# unable to connect to postgres DB container through pyscog2 on a different container using docker compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

here's my docker compose

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: nikitph/portcastdbimage:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - DEBUG = false
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  scraper:
    build: .
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST = db
      - BAR = FOO
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: [ "python3", "./cycloneprocess.py" ]
```

Now from what I have gleaned from stack overflow, there are two options to access this db from a different container

a) use env variable

```
self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=os.environ["DB_HOST"], user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
```

print(os.environ["DB_HOST"]) gives me 'db'. i dont know if thats expected

b) directly use the 'db'

```
 self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host='db', user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
```

none of them seem to be working as no data gets populated. everything works locally so i m quiet confident my code is accurate  All variables like user etc have been checked and rechecked & they work locally. Would really appreciate any help. Everything is on same network btw.

Comment: That setup looks right (I'd prefer the environment variable but both should produce the same results); in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @DavidMaze the db is empty after execution. i can point you to the repo https://github.com/nikitph/portcast although i have tried a bunch of things not in the repo